# next-auth & keycloakProvider: JWT token incomplete

Tags: next.js, jwt, keycloak, next-auth

I have a Next.js application with next-auth using the keycloakProvider that connects to a local instance of keycloak.

Next-Auth is configured as follows:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.ISSUER,
    })
  ],
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This works perfectly fine for logging in and using the `useSession()` hook. However, the session hook only returns name and email, but not fields like "sub" and "roles", which I need. If I query keycloak *via* curl, like so:

```
curl --request POST \                                                                                                                      
  --url 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
  --data-urlencode 'username=<username>' \
  --data-urlencode 'password=<password>' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=<client_id>' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<client_secret>'
```

and paste the JWT onto jwt.io, all data is there. If the JWT is copied from the local browser storage, jwt.io returns "Invalid Signature". The "browser-key" is also much shorter than the "curl-key".

Why does this work *via* curl but not *via* `next-auth`?

Answer (score 1):

The tokens are there,you just need to search at the right places.
You can log the incoming parameter for jwt callback and check all information available:

```
   callbacks: {
    async jwt( {token, user, account, profile} ) {
        console.log("Token: ");
        console.log(token);
        
        console.log("User: ");
        console.log(user);

        console.log("Account: ");
        console.log(account);
        
        console.log("Profile: ");
        console.log(profile);

        if (account) {
            token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        }
        return token;
    },
```

Account object has the tokens:

```
Account: 
{
  provider: 'keycloak',
  type: 'oauth',
  providerAccountId: 'ef7dc6d0-9904-429b-a04e-88abe9569d31',
  access_token: 'eyJhbGciOi...',
  expires_at: 1691538175,
  refresh_expires_in: 1800,
  refresh_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIU...',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  id_token: 'eyJhbGciOiJ...',
  'not-before-policy': 1691533534,
  session_state: '2d4bf885-385b-4dba-81b8-abbe38e900bc',
  scope: 'openid email profile message.read'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved like this:

Firstly if your token is not encrypted you can always transform it to a JSON object with this simple function:

```
const decode = function (token) {
   return JSON.parse(Buffer.from(token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString())
}
```

Now we can profit the NextAuth callbacks 'jwt' and 'session', for modifying token and session objects before sending it to the client:

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        const { sub, roles } = decode(account.access_token)

        token.user = {
          ...user,
          sub,
          roles
        }
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user = token.user
      return session;
    },
  },
})
```

With this approach we are adding the sub and roles attributes to the useSession hook.

Why it's happening this? I haven't check the nextauth source code, but I imagine it only takes the most relevant attributes of keycloak (name and email).

Hope it works.